# Repeating Calculations/Iterations without a specific function

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, programming, infinite-loop, procedural-programming

I am trying to repeat an initial condition many times such that I get a desired final output. ONE final output depends on many subsequent calculations from ONE initial condition. But I want to get a specific final output. I have many given parameters

```
Clear["Global`*"]

tid = 50; taid = 20; tcid = 30; rho = 0.975; pe1 = 4.37; pe2 = 4.4509; qedom = 1021167; 

qeim = 5700; qcid = 529.59; el = 0.655; did = 4.22; dtot = 430932.474; iad = 445002; 

cad = 688723.8554;

qetot = qedom + qeim;

uel = 1 - el;

sigid = 0.20568; rid = 0.02958;

upid = N[Exp[Sqrt[1]*sigid]];

dwid = N[1/upid];

rf = N[Exp[rid*1]];

pid = N[(rf - dwid)/(upid - dwid)]; 

qid = N[1 - pid];

prf2 = 0.001*pe2*qetot-0.01*cad; 

npva = ((rho - rho^(taid + 1))/(1 - rho))*prf2 - 0.01*iad;
```

I would encourage you NOT TO CHANGE the values of the parameters(you are free to change the names if you wish); these are from real data and heavily influence the results. The following parameter "cprd" is the INITIAL CONDITION (given the other parameters) that I want to change many times

```
cprd = 200; 

pin = 63.56*(cprd);(*63.56 is a FIXED constant and "pin" is the product 63.56*cprd*)

prf1[p_] = 0.001*pe1*qedom*el - 0.001*p*qcid - 0.001*pe1*qeim;
```

As you see, ALL THE FOLLOWING calculations depends on ONE chosen value of "pin" and if I change "cprd" all the results would change.

```
stsp = Table[pin*(upid^i), {i, -tid, tid}];

Dimensions[stsp] (*checking this gives a column vector*)

{101}

lensp = Length[stsp]

101

prf1[stsp];

per[i_] := prf1[stsp][[i]];

up[n1_, sig_, T_] := N[Exp[Sqrt[T/n1] sig]];

down[n1_, sig_, T_] := N[1/up[n1, sig, T]];

int[n1_, Rf_, T_] := N[Exp[Rf*(T/n1)]];

P[up_, down_, al_] := N[(al - down)/(up - down)];

Q[up_, down_, al_] := N[1 - P[up, down, al]];

mean[l_List] := Apply[Plus, l]/Length[l];

AmericanOption[p0_, n1_, sig_, T_, Rf_, exercise_Function] := 
  Module[{u = up[n1, sig, T], d = down[n1, sig, T], 
    al = int[n1, Rf, T], p, q, OpRecurse, res}, p = P[u, d, al]; 
   q = Q[u, d, al]; 
   OpRecurse[node_, level_] := 
    OpRecurse[node, level] = 
     If[level == n1, exercise[p0*d^node u^(level - node)], 
      rho*{p, q}.{OpRecurse[node, level + 1], 
          OpRecurse[node + 1, level + 1]} + 
       exercise[p0*d^node u^(level - node)]]; res = OpRecurse[0, 0]; 
   Clear[OpRecurse]; res]; 

AmericanPut[p0_, n1_, sig_, T_, Rf_] := AmericanOption[p0, n1, sig, T, 
  Rf, # &] 

AmericanPut[per[1], tcid, sigid, tcid, rid]  (*just checking*)
95832.1

tabnpvc =Table[AmericanPut[per[i], tcid, sigid, tcid, rid], {i, 1, lensp}];

e1 = 0;

newp = Table[e1, {i, lensp}, {j, lensp}];

Dimensions[newp]

{101, 101}

Table[newp[[i, Min[i + 1, lensp]]] = pid, {i, lensp}]; 


Table[newp[[i, Max[i - 1, 1]]] = qid, {i, lensp}];

    valtern = Max[#, npva] & /@ tabnpvc;
```

The matrix "val" is the MOST IMPORTANT. I want to REPEAT THE ITERATIONS (by changing "cprd") such that difference between the 1st and the 50th column val[[All, 1]]-val[[All, 50]] is first positive and then zero (vector contains positive numbers followed by zeros).

```
val = Table[e1, {i, lensp}, {j, tid + 1}];

val[[All,tid + 1]] = tabnpvc; 

Do[Table[val[[All, i]] = Max[#, npva] & /@ (prf1[stsp] + rho*newp.val[[All, i + 1]]), {i, 
    1, tid}], {tid}];

val // MatrixForm; 

Dimensions[val];

diff = val[[All, 1]] - val[[All, 50]]; (*this vector should ideally contain positive values FOLLOWED BY zeros but NOT negative*)

pos = Position[diff, _?(# < 0 &)] (*this is not desired*)
{{36}, {37}, {38}, {39}, {40}, {41}, {42}, {43}, {44}, {45}, {46},{47}}
```

Finally, just checking with figures

```
valplot[i_, j_] := {stsp[[i]], val[[All, j]][[i]]}; 

val1 = ListLinePlot[Table[valplot[i, 1], {i, 1, lensp}], 
  PlotRange -> All]; 

val2 = ListLinePlot[Table[valplot[i, 50], {i, 1, lensp}], 
  PlotRange -> All]; 

Show[val1, val2]; (*this should be such that the curves don't ever cross but converge to the value of "npva"*)
```

So MY DESIRED FINAL OUTPUT is that the vector "diff" should contain BOTH positive numbers and zeros. It should first be positive and then zeros (maybe "pos" should equal the null vector {}). As you see, you can keep changing the value of "cprd" until you get the desired result

I have no idea on how to do incorporate all this in a "While" or "Do" function. Please help.
Thank You.

Comment: Can't you just encapsulate all that in a function? I'll do it for you, but it's not so hard. And then you can use `While` with that function. It also doesn't seem like you separated out just the parts of your code that are relevant to the question. Please don't just dump your entire notebook into the question (e.g., `val // MatrixForm; ` is a totally useless line). The simpler your question is the more able and willing people will be to answer it.

Comment: @MB1965, is the code Replace[Do[ With[{val = OPsBigFunctionThing[crpd]}, 
   If[FreeQ[diff@val, _?(# < 0 &)], Return[crpd]]], {crpd, 300, 
   1000}], Null -> $Failed]   searching over 300 -1000? When I run, I get "$Failed", does that mean that the vector diff[val] is null over the range 300 to 1000? Would have to change the range then? Also, could you plz explain what you mean by "optimizing?" The code diff@OPsBigFunctionThing[-0.25] // AbsoluteTiming // First gives me 1.688220 (not your 0.741599). If I am right, it just gives the number of seconds taken to compute diff when cprd=-0.25?? Tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the simplest way to tackle this is just to put all your code into a function. You may want to optimize it, because each iteration takes a while, but that's another story.

I did that for you:

```
OPsBigFunctionThing[cprd_]:=
    Module[{
        tid=50,taid=20,tcid=30,rho=0.975,
        pe1=4.37,pe2=4.4509,qedom=1021167,
        qeim=5700,qcid=529.59,el=0.655,
        did=4.22,dtot=430932.474,iad=445002,
        cad=688723.8554,qetot,
        sigid=0.20568,rid=0.02958,uel,
        upid,dwid,rf,pid,qid,prf2,npva,
        pin = 63.56*(cprd)(*63.56 is a FIXED constant and "pin" is the product 63.56*cprd*),
        prf1,stsp,lensp,
        per,up,down,int,
        P,Q,mean,AmericanOption,
        AmericanPut,tabnpvc,e1,
        newp,valtern,val
        },

        qetot=qedom+qeim;
        uel=1-el;
        upid=N[Exp[Sqrt[1]*sigid]];
        dwid=N[1/upid];
        rf=N[Exp[rid*1]];
        pid=N[(rf-dwid)/(upid-dwid)];
        qid=N[1-pid];
        prf2=0.001*pe2*qetot-0.01*cad;
        npva=((rho-rho^(taid+1))/(1-rho))*prf2-0.01*iad;

        prf1[p_] := 0.001*pe1*qedom*el - 0.001*p*qcid - 0.001*pe1*qeim;

        stsp = Table[pin*(upid^i), {i, -tid, tid}];
        lensp = Length[stsp];

        per[i_] := prf1[stsp][[i]];
        up[n1_, sig_, T_] := N[Exp[Sqrt[T/n1] sig]];
        down[n1_, sig_, T_] := N[1/up[n1, sig, T]];

        int[n1_, Rf_, T_] := N[Exp[Rf*(T/n1)]];
        P[up_, down_, al_] := N[(al - down)/(up - down)];
        Q[up_, down_, al_] := N[1 - P[up, down, al]];

        mean[l_List] := Apply[Plus, l]/Length[l];

        AmericanOption[p0_, n1_, sig_, T_, Rf_, exercise_Function] := 
            Module[{
                u = up[n1, sig, T], d = down[n1, sig, T], 
              al = int[n1, Rf, T], p, q, OpRecurse, res}, 
              p = P[u, d, al];
              q = Q[u, d, al]; 
              OpRecurse[node_, level_] := 
                OpRecurse[node, level] = 
                    If[level == n1, exercise[p0*d^node u^(level - node)], 
                        rho*{p, q}.{OpRecurse[node, level + 1], 
                        OpRecurse[node + 1, level + 1]} + 
                        exercise[p0*d^node u^(level - node)]]; 
             res = OpRecurse[0, 0]; 
        Clear[OpRecurse]; 
        res]; 

        AmericanPut[p0_, n1_, sig_, T_, Rf_] := 
            AmericanOption[p0, n1, sig, T, Rf, # &];

        tabnpvc = Table[AmericanPut[per[i], tcid, sigid, tcid, rid], {i, 1, lensp}];
        e1 = 0;

        newp = Table[e1, {i, lensp}, {j, lensp}];
        Do[newp[[i, Min[i + 1, lensp]]] = pid, {i, lensp}]; 
        Table[newp[[i, Max[i - 1, 1]]] = qid, {i, lensp}];
        valtern = Max[#, npva] & /@ tabnpvc;
        val = Table[e1, {i, lensp}, {j, tid + 1}];
        val[[All,tid + 1]] = tabnpvc; 
        Do[
            Table[
                val[[All, i]] = Max[#, npva] & /@ (prf1[stsp] + rho*newp.val[[All, i + 1]]), 
                {i, 1, tid}], 
            {tid}];
        val
]
```

Then we'll make your `diff` its own function:

```
diff[val_] := val[[All, 1]] - val[[All, 50]]
```

And finally use a `Do` loop to try to find a value for you:

```
Replace[
    Do[
        With[{val=OPsBigFunctionThing[crpd]},
            If[FreeQ[diff@val,_?(#<0&)],
                Return[crpd]
                ]
            ],
        {crpd,300,1000}],
    Null->$Failed
    ]
```

Note that you'll probably want to optimize:

```
In[32]:= diff@OPsBigFunctionThing[-0.25] // AbsoluteTiming // First

Out[32]= 0.741599
```

Depending what sort of range you're searching over that could be excruciating.

BTW: I've already searched 1..1000 for you so you can take over from there.

Comment: I don't know a better way to thank you....a Million Thanks!

Comment: @SupratimDasGupta A good way of saying "thank you" is to accept the answer. You should consider browsing through your other questions and accepting the answers that were useful - you haven't done that in almost all cases.

Comment: I would be more than happy to do it. I could not find any tab "accept" in the page.

Comment: There's a little check mark to click next to the answer.

Comment: @MB1965, is the code Replace[Do[ With[{val = OPsBigFunctionThing[crpd]}, 
   If[FreeQ[diff@val, _?(# < 0 &)], Return[crpd]]], {crpd, 300, 
   1000}], Null -> $Failed] searching over 300 to 1000? When I run, I get "$Failed", does that mean that the vector diff[val] is null over the range 300 to 1000? Would have to change the range then? Also, could you plz explain what you mean by "optimizing?" The code diff@OPsBigFunctionThing[-0.25] // AbsoluteTiming // First gives me 1.688220 (not your 0.741599). If I am right, it just gives the number of seconds taken to compute diff when cprd=-0.25?? Tks

Comment: Yeah it's searching over 300 to 1000. I also searched 1 to 300. $Failed means it found nothing. Optimize means speed it up. Diff should be almost instantaneous. The function takes a long time to run so figure out how to speed it up. Look up "functional programming" and see how you can implement those ideas.